# setting windowSoftInputMode:adjustResize does not resize the umano Slideup Panel properly

Tags: android

I am using using slide up panel provided by https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

I have set the `windowSoftInputMode` as `resize` in activity manifest file as follows (I have only one activity)

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

The structure for layout for slideupPanel:

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/customDragViewId">

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/customDragViewId"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            layout="@layout/another_layout" />

        <include
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            layout="@layout/yet_another_layout"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

When i have inflate an `EditText` into the container(`@+id/container`) and get it into focus, the soft keypad is shown. On this, the `@+id/sliding_layout` is re-sized to fit the screen. But the `container` height remains same as the `sliding_layout` when it should be re-sized to end at top of `customDragViewId`. The container only re-sizes when the bottom sliding panel(`@+id/customDragViewId`) is dragged.

What should i do so that the container is always re-sized accordingly ?

Also when i set the panel State to hidden (see the following code), the **sliding_layout** height is not re-sized at all when the keypad shows up. What should i do that **sliding_layout** is re-sized?

```
SlidingUpPanelLayout sliding_layout = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);
sliding_layout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.HIDDEN);
```

**Note**: All the layout elements in bold letters(ex: container) correspond to their ids.

Answer (score 0):

I would love to know if you ever figured this out.

I am having the same issue, I found it leads down to the function that makes the tab bar GONE when the keyboard is opened. If I comment that line it works fine.

Here is that function:

```
getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        Rect r = new Rect();
        getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
        int screenHeight = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().getHeight();

        int keypadHeight = screenHeight - r.bottom;

        if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15) {
            //Keyboard is opened
            nav_view.setVisibility(View.GONE); // If I comment this line the resize works
        }
        else {
            // keyboard is closed
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() {
                nav_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }}, 20);
        }
    }
});
```